# mvn install - Execute

Tags: maven-3

I am executing the following,

mvn -U clean install -T 4C

mvn -U install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Pnpm-application-quick -Papplication

Here mvn install is getting initiated twice. Is there a way to avoid mvn install in the second time which profiles can be applied.

Comment: Doesn't -P state which profile?

Comment: Yes it does and its npm-application-quick and application(which are defined in pom.xml)

Comment: Not understanding your question, you want to merge both commands?

Comment: Initially i tried with merging like, mvn -U clean install -T 4C -Pnpm-application-quick -Papplication. But in the profile we call npm install which actually build failing.So divided into 2 commands, which works fine but execution time is more compared to previous as I am calling the install each time.

Comment: So looking for suggestion to come over from the issue either using merge or independent.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a clean plugin

[Apache Maven Clean Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/)

and ignoring clean errors

[Ignoring Clean Errors](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/ignoring-errors.html)

```
mvn clean -Dmaven.clean.failOnError=false
```

Comment: The question is: I have divided the single command mvn -U clean install -T 4C -Pnpm-application-quick -Papplication into, mvn -U clean install -T 4C and mvn -U install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Pnpm-application-quick -Papplication. With this both times build is passing. But the "install" goal in both is redundant. Is there a way i can overcome from install again in 2nd command?

Comment: Modified my answer